# Identifying recently inserted/updated records in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

ORM framework sometimes doesn't set creation time for audit table. As a workaround I applied:

```
ALTER TABLE audit_log ALTER COLUMN created_on SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

I suspect that this won't fix the problems that ORM framework causes: it could set column to `NULL` so the default value is not triggered.

I cannot search for "broken" records with `WHERE created_on IS NULL` returns lots of old record, indistinguishable from new. So I cannot check if the fix really helps.

My idea is to find some record after the fix with the known date, like (using [xid trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747554/postgresql-using-xid-as-unique-entry-in-a-table)):

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(xmin AS TEXT) AS BIGINT)) 
FROM audit_log
WHERE created_on > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5 day';
```

and using [the magical `xmin` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-system-columns.html) find "newer" rogue `NULL` rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM audit_log
WHERE created_on IS NULL
  AND CAST(CAST(xmin AS TEXT) AS BIGINT) > (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(mintbl.xmin AS TEXT) AS BIGINT))
        FROM audit_log mintbl
        WHERE mintbl.created_on > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5 day');
```

The query return nothing even if I have indirect indication that there are recent "broken" records. Probably I misunderstand the meaning of the special column `xmin`...

**Could you help with *Postgres magical columns* which could be used to identify rows after some insert/update event in the past?**

**PS** It is possible to implement stronger fix to workaround ORM problem: via insert/update trigger, still I'm interested in the original question: how can I find rows that are appeared after some known transaction in the past.

Comment: For the first part, you can use a before trigger that fills in "missing" created_on values.

Comment: Is there a limit to the perversity of your ORM?  What if it updates the wrong row, of the wrong table, on a completely different database connection?

Comment: It is Spring + Hibernate and problems came from `@CreatedDate` - the following class level annotation was missed `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`. Investigation showed the problem had been resolved long ago. Old records indirectly appeared as the new ones but that  perception was wrong. I needed proofs from DB side. Setting `NOT NULL` constraint on PROD was too dramatic change for detecting `NULL`s, maybe some logging triggers were better....

Answer (score -1):

Seems my approach with `MIN(xmin::TEXT:BIGINT)` is working. My indirect indications were based on wrong assumptions, now I don't have doubts.

`xmin` holds the **always incrementing ID** of an instance of the raw, needed by MVCC. If you identify `xmin` of one record in a table:

- almost all previous transactions are with `WHERE xmin::TEXT::BIGINT < ...` (less then given)
- almost all subsequent transactions are with `WHERE xmin::TEXT::BIGINT > ...`

*almost all* because some concurrent transactions might have `xmin` in a close range but the order is not defined. Still those few transactions are not harmful for my analysis.

**UPDATE** Seems the cardinality of `xid` type is low, only 4 bytes: `SELECT pg_column_size('123'::xid);` returns 4.

Seems `xmin` is a globally incremented ID per transaction so some very active tables could cause `xmin` overlapping. After overlapping it is impossible to correlate data based on "fake" monotonicity of `xmin`.

In my case even DB is 5yo it is still near the limit for overlapping:

```
-- 1'705'652'544
select max(xmin::text::int) from audit_log;
```

So the method has limitations, not for production, but could be good enough in some cases for troubleshooting / forensic analysis.

Comment: That is not reliable and purely coincidental. Transaction IDs wrap around, so a greater value could come from an older row.

Comment: `SELECT pg_column_size('123'::xid);` returns 4, so in fact overlapping is quite possible. I assumed that MVCC relies on `xid` monotonicity, but I didn't study docs/sources. For a small table with low INSERT / UPDATE the overlapping might not happens in years. Audit table is such: append only! So the question if MVCC really **assumes monotonicity of xmin**.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. `xmin` is not a property of a record attached to a table but rather a global identity. So other highly active tables could result in `xmin` overlapping ((

Comment: It will work reliably if you have never had transaction ID wraparound yet. If `SELECT pg_current_xact_id();` (available with recent PostgreSQL versions) gives you a value under 4294967296.